# Select all records for entities that always fulfil a specified criterion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this in SQL Server:

```
Name    ID  StartDate   EndDate
--------------------------------
James   232   2005       2015
James   232   2001       2006
Joe     600   1982       2005
Lord    608   2003       2005
Lord    608   2006       2012
Lord    608   1999       2004
Lee     122   2001       2003
Lee     122   2002       2006
```

I need to write a query that only includes the records for a Name/ID if all of their records meet the following criterion:
StartDate is not after 2005 **and** EndDate cannot be before 2005.

The results of the query should therefore be as below:

```
Name    ID  StartDate   EndDate
-------------------------------
James   232    2005       2015
James   232    2001       2006
Joe     600    1982       2005
```

Below is my query, which incorrectly returns three records for Lord and Lee :

```
SELECT * 
FROM #FortuneCompany fc
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM #FortuneCompany fc1 
              WHERE fc1.ID = fc.ID 
                AND YEAR(fc1.StartDate)<=2005 
                AND YEAR(fc1.EndDate)>=2005
              )
```

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: `where startdate <= 2005 and enddate >= 2005`.

Comment: Why joe shouldn't be included `
Joe     600    1982       2005` 1982 is less than 2005 and 2006 is greater than 2005, so it should be included

Comment: SELECT *
FROM  #FortuneCompany
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM  #FortuneCompany fc1
      WHERE fc1.ID = fc.ID
                      AND YEAR(fc1.StartDate)<=2005
                      AND YEAR(fc1.EndDate)>=2005)  this is my query

Comment: @Arasu check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT Name, ID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE StartDate <= '2005-01-01' AND Enddate >= '2005-01-01'
```

Comment: I guess OP wants  WHERE StartDate <= '2005-12-31' AND Enddate >= '2005-01-01', to include the whole years. (Just guessing...)

Comment: Oops, I missed the "**equal** or greater than 2005".  I've corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, ID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate <= 2005 
AND Enddate >= 2005
```

No need for sub-query. I assume StartDate and EndDate columns are int. Only if they are date do you need to use the YEAR() function. In your question the top and bottom row of the three results you've said shouldn't be returned actually do meet the criteria.

Comment: this query does not give correct answer read my question clearly

Comment: @Arasu -- well, see that's the problem.   Your question is *not* clear.  Why don't you work on that first.

Comment: It should be `>=` instead of `=>`

Answer (score 0):

If correctly understood you don't want to select rows for user at all if there is at least 1 wrong entry for that user. To achieve that you can use `NOT IN` in following:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT Name, ID, StartDate, EndDate
FROM #FortuneCompany fc
WHERE Name NOT IN(
        SELECT Name
        FROM #FortuneCompany fc
        WHERE StartDate > 2005 
        OR Enddate < 2005)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #FortuneCompany
(
   Name NVARCHAR(40),
   ID INT,
   StartDate INT,
   EndDate INT
)
INSERT INTO #FortuneCompany VALUES
('James',232, 2005, 2015),
('James',232, 2001, 2006),
('Joe'  ,600, 1982, 2005),
('Lord' ,608, 2003, 2005),
('Lord' ,608, 2006, 2012),
('Lord' ,608, 1999, 2004),
('Lee'  ,122, 2001, 2003),
('Lee'  ,122, 2002, 2006)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Name    ID  StartDate   EndDate
James   232 2005        2015
James   232 2001        2006
Joe     600 1982        2005
```

Comment: i don't want the result who are all fullfill this condition, i have the  result  who fullfill this condition only

Comment: this include name lee and lord but i dont want these names because lee has startdate 2001 and 2003 which is my condition enddate is equal or greate than 2005 is not fullfilled and then name lord also

Comment: this would be the correct answer. if it is working for you - @Arasu - please marked as answer.